# Pegar o valor de um timepicker

Tags: java, kotlin, datepicker

tenho o segunite codigo , onde imprimo valor em " di " :

```
private fun clickDatePicker(view: View) {
        var c: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
         TimePickerDialog(this, TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { _, HH, mi ->
            val di = "$HH:$mi"
            ifBinding.horaini.text = di
        }, c.get(Calendar.HOUR),
            c.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true).show()
    }

----------------------
Gostaria de usar esse valor apurado no codigo abaixo para fazer os calculos

 object LocalTimeAddSubtractExample {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            val time: LocalTime = LocalTime.of(5, 0, 0) --> usar "di" aqui
            //ifBinding.Inicio.text = ("Inicio de Viagem"+time)
            System.out.println("Inicio da Jornada "+time)
            // Add hours, minutes, or seconds
            val paUm: LocalTime = time.plusHours(3).plusMinutes(30)
            System.out.println("Primeira Parada (Café) " +paUm)
            val paDois: LocalTime = time.plusHours(4)
            System.out.println("Reinicio "+paDois)
            val paTres: LocalTime = time.plusHours(7).plusMinutes(30)
            System.out.println("Segunda Parada (Almoço) "+paTres)
            val paQuatro: LocalTime = time.plusHours(8).plusMinutes(30)
            System.out.println("Reinicio "+paQuatro)
            val paCinco: LocalTime = time.plusHours(12)
            System.out.println("Terceira Parada (Lanche) "+paCinco)
            val paSeis: LocalTime = time.plusHours(12).plusMinutes(30)
            System.out.println("Reinicio "+paSeis)
            val paSete: LocalTime = time.plusHours(16)
            System.out.println("Quarta Parada (descanso de 8 horas) "+paSete)
            val paOito: LocalTime = time.plusHours(24)
            System.out.println("Reinicio "+paOito)


        }
    }
```

Certo da ajuda , agradeço antecipadamente.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Já que está trabahado com um objeto, não poderia simplesmente chamar a função do mesmo dentro do set?

```
private fun clickDatePicker(view: View) {
    var c: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
     TimePickerDialog(this, TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { _, HH, mi ->
        val di = "$HH:$mi"
        ifBinding.horaini.text = di
        LocalTimeAddSubtractExample.main(Array(di))
    }, c.get(Calendar.HOUR),
        c.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true).show()
}

object LocalTimeAddSubtractExample {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val time: LocalTime = args[0]
        //ifBinding.Inicio.text = ("Inicio de Viagem"+time)
        System.out.println("Inicio da Jornada "+time)
        // Add hours, minutes, or seconds
        val paUm: LocalTime = time.plusHours(3).plusMinutes(30)
        System.out.println("Primeira Parada (Café) " +paUm)
        val paDois: LocalTime = time.plusHours(4)
        System.out.println("Reinicio "+paDois)
        val paTres: LocalTime = time.plusHours(7).plusMinutes(30)
        System.out.println("Segunda Parada (Almoço) "+paTres)
        val paQuatro: LocalTime = time.plusHours(8).plusMinutes(30)
        System.out.println("Reinicio "+paQuatro)
        val paCinco: LocalTime = time.plusHours(12)
        System.out.println("Terceira Parada (Lanche) "+paCinco)
        val paSeis: LocalTime = time.plusHours(12).plusMinutes(30)
        System.out.println("Reinicio "+paSeis)
        val paSete: LocalTime = time.plusHours(16)
        System.out.println("Quarta Parada (descanso de 8 horas) "+paSete)
        val paOito: LocalTime = time.plusHours(24)
        System.out.println("Reinicio "+paOito)


    }
}
```

Caso não seja o que procura, favor melhorar sua pergunta, dando mais detalhes e explicações.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta meu querido , testei a sua alteração e deu alguns erros , mas vamos lá , eu preciso que o horario seja indicado pelo usuario e na seguencia vai se somando o periodo que ele trabalha e descansa ( é a jornada de uma motorista de caminhão)